# Find & replace certain text within a node in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I've got an XML in which I've got a number of nodes which contain paths, in which I (may) need to change some of the path if certain information is found.

For example, a node like this may exist:

```
<File name="dev\Desktop\Working\Test\English\1312\myopic.dll">
```

I need to find all paths that have a 4 digit number in the path (like '1312' above), and change this to something like %NUM%.

What's the best approach? My first thoughts were to use RegEx, but from some searching it seems like that's a bad idea?

Maybe LINQ to XML (I have some limited experience with that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Regex here is the most effecint solution here, It is not bad idea at all

```
string path = @""<File name=""dev\Desktop\Working\Test\English\1312\myopic.dll"">";
string pattern = @"\d\d\d\d";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string replacement = "%NUM%";

string result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
//result is: <File name="dev\Desktop\Working\Test\English\%NUM%\myopic.dll">
```

Answer (score 1):

It is XML, so why not use [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx).

On the other hand, if this is a one-time thing and you want KNOW that the pattern won't occur in the wrong parts of your XML, regex would be much faster to implement.

```
newFileContents = Regex.Replace(
   fileContents,
   @"(?<=dev\\Desktop\\Working\\Test\\English\\)\d+",
   "%num%);
```